# Approach for the problem UVA 10461 Difference

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I could not understand how to proceed with this problem — [UVA 10461](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1402)

I could see people doing bfs twice, but I'm not able to see how it solves the problem. I'm just clueless it would be really helpful if someone could explain it in simple terms.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show me with like a diagram on how this works - Beginner here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the earliest any task T can proceed?  All the tasks reachable from T by going forward over dependency arrows must go first. You can find those by searching from T to sum the weights of reachable nodes.

What is the latest any task U can proceed?  All the tasks reachable from U by going backward over dependency arrows must come later. Again you can find those by searching from U to sum the weights of reachable nodes.

The graph is a DAG, not necessarily connected. Cycles don't make sense. Simple DFS will suffice for the searches.

There are two remaining subproblems. First, you'd like to avoid doing 2N searches for a graph of N nodes. This isn't hard. The sum of weights of a node's children will be the same no matter where the search starts, so it's sufficient to do a single search forward over edges to find all the earliest times and over back edges to find the latest times.

The second subproblem is how to represent the graph. We're allowed to have up to 500 vertices, but also no more than 500 edges. Consequently the graph is likely to  be sparse. Most efficient for DAG seach would be an adjacency list.  You'll need  two of these: one for forward edges and one for reverse.

Suppose you have built an adjacency list representation where `a[i].adj` is a list of nodes adjacent (forward) to node `i` and task durations are in array `d[]`. Suppose also that as you built the adjacency matrix you kept track of how many in-edges there were for each vertex in an array `ni[]`. We want to store earliest times in array `e[]`.

Remember searching a DAG requires a pass over all nodes to find the starting points: those with no in-edges (called sources) for the forward search and those with no out-edges (called sinks) for the back-edge search.

Then pseudocode for the forward search would look like this

```
def find_all_earliest()
  for i = 1 to v
    e[i] = UNASSIGNED
  for i = 1 to v
    if ni[i] = 0 // found a source
      find_earliest(i)

// Return the sum of node weights of subtree rooted at `i`.
def find_earliest(i)
  if e[i] != UNASSIGNED // Use already-computed value if there is one.
    return e[i]
  decendant_sum = 0
  for a in a[i].adj
    decendant_sum += find_earliest(a)
  e[i] = decendant_sum
  return decendant_sum + d[i]
```

When this is done `e[i]` contains the earliest start time for task `i`.  The latest search will be symmetric. The answer is the differences between corresponding earliest and latest times.

After this, `e[i]` contains the earliest start time of the task `i`.